# Is it always possible to transform multiple spatial selects with while loop and variables into a single query without using temp tables in sql?

Tags: sql-server, loops, t-sql, variables

This problem can be solved with temp table, however, **I don't want to use Temp table or var table**, this question is mostly for my personal educational purposes.

I inherited the following SQL:

```
DECLARE  @i int = 993

while @i <=1000
begin
declare @lat nvarchar(20)
select top 1 @lat = SUBSTRING(Address,0,CHARINDEX(',',Address,0)) from dbo.rent
    where id  = @i; 
declare @lon nvarchar(20)
select top 1 @lon = SUBSTRING(Address,CHARINDEX(',',Address)+1,LEN(Address)) from dbo.rent
    where id  = @i 


declare @p GEOGRAPHY =  GEOGRAPHY::STGeomFromText('POINT('+ @lat +' '+@lon+')', 4326)


select price/LivingArea sq_m, (price/LivingArea)/avg_sq_m, * from
(select     (sum(price)/sum(LivingArea)) avg_sq_m,  count(1) cnt, @i id from 
        (select  *, GEOGRAPHY::STGeomFromText('POINT('+ 
        convert(nvarchar(20), SUBSTRING(Address,0,CHARINDEX(',',Address,0)))+' '+
        convert( nvarchar(20), SUBSTRING(Address,CHARINDEX(',',Address)+1,LEN(Address)))+')', 4326)
            .STBuffer(500).STIntersects(@p) as [Intersects]
            from dbo.rent
            where Address is not null 
        ) s
    where [Intersects] = 1) prox
    inner join dbo.rent r on  prox.id = r.id
    set @i = @i+1
end
```

it is used to analyze property prices per square meter that are in proximity and compare them to see which ones are cheaper...

Problem: a mechanism for calling has to be moved from `C#` to `SQL` and all queries have to be combined into a single result (now you get one row per one while run), i.e `@i` and `@p` has to go and become `while id < x and id > y` or somehow magically joined,

the procedure is a cut down version of actual thing but having a solution to the above I will have no problem making the whole thing work...

I am of the opinion that any SQL mechanism with variables and loops can be transformed to a single SQL statement, hence the question.

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f72284/27)

Comment: SqlFiddle posted is invalid - as address is 't' for all records

Comment: @DawoodAwan Fixed I think

Comment: Not sure that *every* loop can be converted to a set based approach, but most of the times, a tally table (a.k.a numbers table)  can easily replace loops.

Comment: Reports are infinitely faster when they work over properly designed reporting tables. Creating geographies on the fly for example means you can't use any spatial indexes. Why not just store the points and buffers in the table and index them? Or the more obvious thing, why buffer the *individual locations* instead of the one and only search point?

Comment: @MatasVaitkevicius in this case the loop seems to be needed only due to the inefficient query and schema. Fix that and you could have a far simpler and faster query. For example, unless you *really* need complex shapes, spatial queries will always be slower than simple range queries over indexed coordinate fields, eg `lat between @minLat and @maxLat and lon ....`. You can use that to quickly filter items in a bounding box and then use the spatial functions to calculate distances.

Comment: @MatasVaitkevicius What does `Address` look like? The `SUBSTRING` calls seem to do nothing more than replace `,` with a space. You may be able to  use `GEOGRAPHY::STGeomFromText('POINT(' + REPLACE(Address, ',', ' ') +')' )`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos like this, '36.603,-6.22352' comma separated strings  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f72284/27

Comment: @MatasVaitkevicius in that case you can get rid of the `SUBSTRING` calls. The entire loop can be replaced with an INNER JOIN where the conditions are the *distance* between the two apartments and `rent1.ID!=rent2.ID` to prevent comparing an appartment with itself. It will be slow though, but probably faster than trying to perform the N comparisons in a loop

Comment: @MatasVaitkevicius you can add a calculated column to the `Rent` table to return the location, eg `ALTER TABLE Rent ADD Location AS GEOGRAPHY::STGeomFromText('POINT(' + REPLACE(Address, ',', ' ') +')' )`. You can make it PERSISTED so the value is calculated only once, when the `Address` value changes.

Comment: @MatasVaitkevicius unfortunately the distance calculation can't be accelerated by indexes or precalculated. You still have to add a bounding box to the two tables, so you don't end up comparing apartments outside your target area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done, in this specific case 'discovery' that was necessary was the ability to perform `JOIN`s on `Point` e.g ability to join tables on proximity (another a small cheat was to aggregate point-strings to actual points, but it's just an optimization). Once this is done, a query could be rewritten as follows:

```
SELECT adds.Url,
adds.Price/adds.LivingArea Sqm,
(adds.Price/adds.LivingArea)/k1.sale1Avg ratio,
       *
   FROM
   (SELECT baseid,
          count(k1Rent.rentid) rent1kCount,
          sum(k1Rent.RperSqM)/(count(k1Rent.rentid)) AS rent1kAvgSqM,
          count(around1k.SaleId) sale1kCount,
          (sum(k1sale.price)/sum(k1Sale.LivingArea)) sale1Avg,
          (sum(k1sale.price)/sum(k1Sale.LivingArea))/((sum(k1Rent.RperSqM)/(count(k1Rent.rentid)))*12) years --*
FROM
     (SELECT sa.id baseid,
             s.id saleid,
             s.RoomCount,
             POINT
      FROM SpatialAnalysis sa
      INNER JOIN Sale s ON s.Id = SaleId
      WHERE sa.SalesIn1kRadiusCount IS NULL) AS base
   JOIN SpatialAnalysis around1k ON base.Point.STBuffer(1000).STIntersects(around1k.Point) = 1
   LEFT OUTER JOIN
     (SELECT id rentid,
             rc,
             Price/avgRoomSize RperSqM
      FROM
        (SELECT *
         FROM
           (SELECT rc,
                   sum(avgArea*c)/sum(c) avgRoomSize
            FROM
              (SELECT roomcount rc,
                      avg(livingarea) avgArea,
                      count(1) c
               FROM Rent
               WHERE url LIKE '%systemname%'
                 AND LivingArea IS NOT NULL
               GROUP BY RoomCount
               UNION
                 (SELECT roomcount rc,
                         avg(livingarea) avgArea,
                         count(1) c
                  FROM sale
                  WHERE url LIKE '%systemname%'
                    AND LivingArea IS NOT NULL
                  GROUP BY RoomCount))uni
            GROUP BY rc) avgRoom) avgrents
      JOIN rent r ON r.RoomCount = avgrents.rc) k1Rent ON k1Rent.rentid =around1k.RentId
   AND base.RoomCount = k1Rent.rc
   LEFT OUTER JOIN Sale k1Sale ON k1Sale.Id = around1k.SaleId
   AND base.RoomCount = k1Sale.RoomCount
   GROUP BY baseid) k1
 left outer join SpatialAnalysis sp on sp.Id = baseid
 left outer join Sale adds on adds.Id = sp.SaleId
 where adds.Price < 250000
 order by  years, ratio
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question properly (Remove the need for loops and return one data set) then you can use CTE (Common Table Expressions) for the Lats, Lons and Geog variables.

You;re SQLFIddle was referencing a database called "webanalyser" so I removed that from the query below

However, the query will not return anything as the sample data has wrong data for address column.

```
;WITH cteLatsLongs
AS(
    SELECT
         lat    = SUBSTRING(Address, 0, CHARINDEX(',', Address, 0))
        ,lon    = SUBSTRING(Address, CHARINDEX(',', Address) + 1, LEN(Address))
    FROM dbo.rent
)
,cteGeogs
AS(
    SELECT
        Geog = GEOGRAPHY ::STGeomFromText('POINT(' + LL.lat + ' ' + LL.lon + ')', 4326)
    FROM cteLatsLongs LL
),cteIntersects
AS(
    SELECT *, 
            GEOGRAPHY::STGeomFromText('POINT(' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20), SUBSTRING(Address, 0, CHARINDEX(',', Address, 0))) + ' ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20), SUBSTRING(Address, CHARINDEX(',', Address) + 1, LEN(Address))) + ')', 4326).STBuffer(500).STIntersects(G.Geog) AS [Intersects]
    FROM dbo.rent
    CROSS APPLY cteGeogs G
)
    SELECT avg_sq_m = (SUM(price) / SUM(LivingArea)), COUNT(1) cnt
    FROM
        cteIntersects I
    WHERE I.[Intersects] = 1
```

Comment: the SQL Fiddle is wrong, only has one line `Select * from dbo.rent`

Comment: Hi Geezer, but this way you get only one record (id = 993), I think I have fixed the sql fiddle sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f72284/27

Comment: I didn't realize that if i select and run it creates a new version, lol

Comment: I've updated the answer but it might not be what you're after as I might be misunderstanding what you're after